# Sharepoint Alerts on List Folders

Tags: sharepoint, list, directory

I would like to programatically add alert to folders inside a sharepoint list. I have found how to set alerts to a list and this works perfect.

Could someone please help me on how to set alerts to a specific folder which is inside a list.

Below is the code i currently have which sets alerts only to the list.

```
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://site/"))
{
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    SPUser user = web.SiteUsers["domain\\user"];
SPAlert newAlert = user.Alerts.Add();
newAlert.AlertType = SPAlertType.List;
newAlert.List = web.Lists["Documents"];
newAlert.EventType = SPEventType.All;
newAlert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate;
//passing true to Update method will send alert confirmation mail
newAlert.Update(true);
}
}
```

Your help will be much appreciated

**THIS QUESTION IS RESOLVED! PLEASE SEE MY POST BELOW WITH THE LINK - SEE - [LINK](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/56f503f1-fc8e-4d4d-bee5-450e0f8726e3?prof=required)**

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible out of the box, but after googling I found an interesting possibility though, check out Mike Walsh's answer on [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/270d7d0a-e950-4b38-a0a4-ebfcdd2940d9), it entails creating a view in the folder and then attaching the alert to that view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the line with

```
newAlert.List = web.Lists["Documents"];
```

With

```
SPFolder fldr = web.GetFolder("/ListName/FolderName");
newAlert.Item=fldr.Item;
```

Also note that Folder is also another item.

Comment: Hi Kusek Thank you for the answer. I tried as you mentioned  but it is throwing an error:

Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The object specified does not belong to a list
.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetItem(String strUrl, Boolean bFile, Boolean c
acheRowsetAndId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder.get_Item()
   at Alerts_Programatically.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\........\Program.cs:line 23

YOUR HELP WILL BE MUCH APPRECIATED! THANK YOU

Comment: i tried fixing and managed to get rid of the above error but now getting this one: any ideas please?

Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Item property cannot be set for this type of alert.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlert.set_Item(SPListItem value)
   at Alerts_Programatically.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\......\Program.cs:line 23